# Accessing a created object from another class

Tags: java

For homework I'm asked to seperate a nested class from the main class.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/**
 This program displays the growth of an investment.
*/
public class InvestmentViewer2
{ public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 // The button to trigger the calculation
 JButton button = new JButton("Add Interest");
 // The application adds interest to this bank account
 final BankAccount account = new BankAccount(INITIAL_BALANCE);
 // The label for displaying the results
 final JLabel label = new JLabel("balance: " + account.getBalance());
 // The panel that holds the user interface components
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.add(button);
 panel.add(label);
 frame.add(panel);

 class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener
 {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
 {
 double interest = account.getBalance()
 * INTEREST_RATE / 100;
 account.deposit(interest);
 label.setText(
 "balance: " + account.getBalance());
 }
 }
 ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
 button.addActionListener(listener);
 frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 private static final double INTEREST_RATE = 10;
 private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 1000;
 private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
 private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
}
```

I took the class AddInterestListener out of the main class, and put it in a new file. Now the account.getBalance() doesn't work anymore. I can't find how I would let the new class AddInterestListener target the account object that was created in the main class.

I also have a simple BankAccount class that creates the object. That has the 2 methods deposit(double x) and getBalance().

There is a hint on the homework question:  Store a reference to
the bank account. Add a constructor to the listener class that sets the reference.

I don't understand what they are saying. I've tried extending the class and then using super. to reach the method, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Where is the method for `getBalance()`? I don't see it in your class anywhere.

Comment: Well, if I asked you to "store a reference" in a class, how would you do that?  Break down that requirement step by step and handle one step at a time.

Comment: The problem is most likely that the problem is too easy and the terminology is confusing you.  By the hint they are saying that your primary class should be a listener and it should "Store a reference to the bank account", so the listener should have a line like "BankAccount bankAccount;' (This is a reference), then in the listener's constructor it should take a BankAccount as a parameter and save it as "bankAccount"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a constructor on AddInterestListener, pass in the Account object as a parameter and stored it in a field on the AddInterestListener class...

```
public class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener {
     private final Account account;

     public AddInterestListener(final Account account) {
         this.account = account;
     }

     public void actionPerformed(Event e) {
      ...
          account.deposit(interest);
      ...
     }
}
```